# Azure durable function deployment options for multiple versions of a function app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure functions app, which contains durable functions. I need to deploy multiple versions of durable functions side-by-side where they could be running for a while before they complete. I want to make sure I'm allowing the previous versions to complete without breaking orchestrations when the sequence or checkpoint data result changes. I'm aware of options like using slots and versioning inside of code, but that doesn't seem viable for longer running orchestrations.

I'm looking at the application router approach described here: [Zero-downtime deployment for Durable Functions: Application Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-zero-downtime-deployment#application-routing)

Curious if anyone has used this approach and if there are other recommended approaches outside of the ones mentioned in that article.

Function proxies seem interesting here for the multiple version routing portion, but it not totally clear how to leverage it to perform something similar to the application router idea.

Answer (score 0):

We are using 2 slots, 1 storage account, unique task hub names per slot. Has been working well so far for a few months.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).